# Best practices for tracking ingested data sources

Tags: postgresql, data-integrity, data-validation

I am in the process of creating an ingestion pipeline wherein there exists a step of periodically reading new .csv files and storing them into a postgres database. This step is functioning, however it is currently impractical/time-consuming to verify if the data in any certain file has been fully and correctly ingested into the database. I am essentially operating in blind trust that the database is a point of truth, but I would like to be able to be a little more certain.

The first step I was planning to take is to store runtime metadata during ingestion jobs (e.g. filename, time of ingestion, job result) in its own table in the database. While this won't speak to the *integrity* of the data, it would at least allow some insight into what has been processed.

Any guidance on best practices and what else I can do re: data validation for a setup like this would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I'll offer some quick hits from personal experience:

1. **Store the original unmodified data somewhere.** There will come a time where you find 6 months down the road you have been multiplying by your calibration value instead of adding it. Recovering from this sort of error is much easier if you can just throw out the corrupted observations and re-import from original sources. CSVs are text, they compress well with zstd, back them up on slow storage Just In Case You Need Them.
2. **Sanity check your input data.** Some domain-specific knowledge is necessary here, but it will save a lot of head-scratching if you can flag data points that are clearly out of bounds. Don't reject or delete them (see #1), just make them easy to find later.
3. **Monitor your pipeline and alert if the flow stops unexpectedly.** Its faster to catch up from a 2 hour outage than from a 96 hour outage. A reliable logging infrastructure goes a long way to telling you what happened (or what *didn't* happen).
4. **Look for opportunities to build long-term models & compare data from other sources.** People are good at pictures, visualizations can help find subtle shifts in data that are indications of problems.
5. **Document, document, document.** Make sure someone else can figure out how you designed, built, and installed your software so they can put it back together when the hard drive fails while you are on vacation in Fiji.

> it is currently impractical/time-consuming to verify if the data in any certain file has been fully and correctly ingested into the database

You will have *PLENTY* of time to write said verification tools when you find your entire dataset is worthless because of an off-by-1 error in someone's code. "Why is there never enough time to do it right the first time, but plenty of time to do it right the second time?"

Budget time now to build the infrastructure, while things are simple and malleable.